# Entity Framework Code First, получить объект через ключ

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть проект на C#, использующий Entity Framework Code First

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{    
    public DatabaseContext() : base("name=DatabaseContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DatabaseContext>());
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    public void Init(){}

    //Множество объектов
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Как видно, EntityFramework хранит некое множество объектов Projects. В объекте Project есть поле Items, которое представляет из себя коллекцию

```
public class Project
{
    public Project(){}

    [Key]
    public int Id{ get;set;}

    //Коллекция
    ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Диаграмма базы данных, созданной Entity Framework выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через SQL получить строку из таблицы Item, зная Id, просто элементарно.

```
Select * FROM dbo.Items where Id=1
```

**Вопрос:** А как тоже самое сделать используя средства Entity Framework, не подгружая в программу все коллекции Items из проектов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте в проект

```
public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Тогда вам останется только воспользоваться методом [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
var item = context.Items.Find(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [LINQ](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.1.php).

Как вариант:

```
int id = 1;
var item = items.Where(t => t.Id==id).First();
```

Или:

```
int id = 1;
var item = items.First(t => t.Id==id);
```

Comment: Вот только объекта items не существует

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр, ну так добавьте. Зачем мучиться?

Comment: @АндрейNOP проекты будут динамично удаляться и добавляться, это сделает, на мой взгляд, код грязным

Comment: С чего вы взяли?

Comment: @ТрипольскийПетр, глупости какие-то. А то что вам придется лезть в одну таблицу только через другую - от этого код станет чище? И sql оптимальнее? Так что ли?

Comment: @Streletz, у `First` есть [перегрузка, принимающая предикат](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb535183(v=vs.110).aspx). `Where` не нужен

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не создавать лишних DbSet в виде публичных свойств у экземпляра класса DbContext их можно получать динамично там, где вам нужно

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext()) 
{     
    var item=context.Set<Item>().Find(id);
}
```

Подобные объекты так же будут мониториться Entity Framework и их изменения будут отражены в базе данных

Comment: А что значит лишние DbSet? Как у вас тогда будет возможна работа с миграциями? Ведь каждый сет соответствует сущности и таблице в БД? И будет ли возможна работа с контекстом полученным через DI, если он у вас в конце блока using будет тут же убит?

Comment: @Bulson необязательно использовать Using, тут всё на ваше усмотрение. В моем проекте не используются миграции, так как структура базы данных не будет изменяться, не могу уточнить. А вот допускать наличие Item, не привязанных к Project, нельзя... И если поле публичное, то туда рано или поздно точно что-нибудь добавят другие программисты.

Comment: Что мешает другим программистам добавлять что-нибудь этим же самым способом? Для ограничения доступа используются роли.

Comment: @АндрейNOP На вкус и цвет товарища нет, но лично на мой взгляд отсутствие публичного DbSet с объектами Item не даст ненамеренно добавить туда что-нибудь

Comment: Это тоже самое, что для того чтобы у вас не украли из квартиры вещи вы вешаете на дверь занавеску, с изображением стены, надеясь, что никто не догадается что за ней дверь, вместо того, чтобы поставить нормальный замок и раздать ключи от него только членам семьи. Ваш метод ни от чего не защищает, а лишь усложняет жизнь вам же

Comment: @АндрейNOP эмм, да( Дайте пожалуйста  почитать что нибудь про "роли", о которых вы говорили выше

Comment: Ну вот, например, для начала: https://professorweb.ru/my/sql-server/2012/level3/3_12.php

Comment: @АндрейNOP подобные настройки можно выставить SQL запросами, но уже после создания базы. Можно ли выставить их из Entity Framework?

Comment: Не знаю насчет специального механизма в EF, но в EF можно также вызвать SQL